# Is it possible to flatten sub-object fields while parsing with serde_json?

Tags: json, rust, serde

`#[serde(rename)]` seems to be the right option, but the documentation  does not state if it is possible or how to do it.

This JSON object:

```json
{
   "name" : "myobject"
   "info" : 
   {
      "counter" : "3"
      "foo" : "bar"
   }
}
```

The corresponding *flat* Rust struct should be:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Object {
    name: String,
    #[serde(rename="info.counter")] // wrong syntax here !!
    count: i32,
    #[serde(rename="info::foo")] // neither this works
    foo: String,
}
```

Comment: As a note, there's no *performance* downside to having a nested struct; there's only code organization to worry about.

Comment: This is not possible yet: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/119

Comment: Using `#[serde(deserialize_with = "path")]` is another good alternative. https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/868

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this with attributes, but you can write your own `Deserialize` impl for your `Object` type that deserializes first to some intermediate helper representation and then rearranges the data into the desired struct.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Object {
    name: String,
    count: i32,
    foo: String,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Object {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
        where D: Deserializer<'de>
    {
        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        struct Outer {
            name: String,
            info: Inner,
        }

        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        struct Inner {
            count: i32,
            foo: String,
        }

        let helper = Outer::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        Ok(Object {
            name: helper.name,
            count: helper.info.count,
            foo: helper.info.foo,
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let j = r#"{
                 "name": "myobject",
                 "info": {
                   "count": 3,
                   "foo": "bar"
                 }
               }"#;

    println!("{:#?}", serde_json::from_str::<Object>(j).unwrap());
}
```

The output is:

```
Object {
    name: "myobject",
    count: 3,
    foo: "bar"
}
```

---

There are three materially different places where insignificant nesting arises:

1. adjacent to other fields
2. by itself at the top level
3. by itself below the top level

All three require different approaches. #1 is observed in this question.

To solve #2 or #3, see [Is there a way to omit wrapper/root objects when deserializing objects with Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54657873/155423)